# How to add an object at index 0, when insertObject throws an error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

how can we add an object to a NSMutableArray at index 0, when the first index was previously removed? `insertObject` does not work :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

When the screen moves to the right, i remove the first index of the array (which is not visible anymore) and add it to the right. But if i want to **go back to the left, i have to add the previously removed image** (now at index 2, but the images are the same, so it does not really matter if i just add another image). `addObject` adds an object at the end of the array, and insertObject throws an error...

Would you know any way to fix this?

```
linesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:lines1, lines2, lines3, nil];

//left direction : add the object at index 0
if (offsetParam >= offset1){
    CCSprite *temp = [[sprites objectAtIndex:1] retain];
    [sprites removeObjectAtIndex:2];
    [sprites insertObject:temp atIndex:0];//****CRASH HERE****
    temp.position = ccp(-offset1-spriteWidth, temp.position.y);
    [temp release];
    offset1 += spriteWidth;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. Your error message indicates strongly that you're crashing on the previous line. In fact, you can _always_ insert an object at index 0, even if the array is empty.

Comment: Have you actually verified that it crashes at the insertObject line?  The output you posted looks like the line above(the removeObjectAt) is the problematic one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read that exception a little closer

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '* -[__NSArrayM **removeObjectAtIndex:**]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

You will see that it's actually a crash on the line right before the one you mention.  This line is fine:

```
[sprites insertObject:temp atIndex:0];//CRASH HERE****
```

It the previous one that crashes:

```
[sprites removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

It looks like you have an array with 2 items, (indices 0 and 1) so removing index 2 crashes because there is no index 2.

Answer (score 1):

You're crashing on the line before, where you try to manipulate the object at index 2. The error message clearly states that you're trying to remove an object, and from index 2. The only place you do that in the code you've posted is the line

```
[sprites removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

Your `sprites` array does not have as many objects as you think it does.

You can *always* insert into an `NSMutableArray`'s index 0; it works for an empty array, or for an array with any number of objects.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the initWithObjects is nil terminated, meaning the first nil the method encounters will be the last one in the list.  Based on the code you posted, my hunch is that lines3 is nil, causing your list to be of size 2, which would cause

```
[sprites removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

To fail with the error message you posted.  Check with the debugger and verify that lines1,lines2, and lines3 are not nil

Comment: While this is a good and sometimes overlooked point, those are two entirely different arrays -- `sprites` and `linesArray`.

Comment: My bad, he doesnt actually use linesArray in the code he posted, sort of odd to include it then.